# Applications are being opened by IE instead of running normally

Tags: windows-xp, file-extension

**I rewrote the Question to add everything that i tried so far.**

- Many of my applications are being opened by Internet Explorer. (not
  all)
- For example when I run `Firefox.exe` **(from shortcut)** I get IE run
  instead, with the following URL

  http:  //  %22d/  Browser/firefox.exe%22
  (I added spaces to prevent link creation)

  1. the shortcut target is: ***"D:\Browser\firefox.exe"***
  2. when I attempted to open firefox.exe from it's folder the results were
     the same as the previous one
  3. I attempted to open it by cmd, so i navigated with cmd to the FF path
     then wrote: **firefox.exe**
  4. the was the same except that the URL was:

     http:  //  Firefox.exe/
  5. when i jsut write **firefox** the result URL was:

  http:  //  Firefox/
  (is it some kind of parameter or something??)

  6. trying the same with **chrome** resulted the same results as the previous
     tests.
  7. I tried creating a new user (adminstartor) but the problem still
     there.
  8. I tried every registry key with exe on it (not sure if i tried them
     all) no change
  9. I tried removing IE but came back by itself somehow, meanwhile IE is
     removed, FF and its fellow apps gave me ***open with*** window
  10. I tried reinstalling the applications but it just no use.

**Time Line:** (as requested from @Daredev)

11. I don't know when it happened because the computer is for the
     company i work for and it was like that since i got it. (The IT
     there gave up on the problem lon time ago!).
12. applications were installed already are "firefox" and "XPS viewer"
     .
13. applications were working after the problem everything except what
     uses browsing (MS help viewer, XPS viewer, firefox-even I've re
     installed it-, opera, chrome)
14. that what I thought but after installing Maxthon , comodoDragon
     this theory was blown away.

**system info:**
1- windows xp professional service pack 3
2- system fully patched: Yes
3- anti-virus up to date: Yes
4- same behavior when booting into safe mode: Yes

Comment: *Many* of your apps (EXEs) are being opened by IE, but not *all*?

Comment: @Karan yes not all

Comment: You should enter in the cmd : `cd "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\"` and then `firefox.exe`. Let us know what happens.

Comment: When you open Firefox, are you using the shortcut icon on your desktop?  What happens if you go directly to C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\ and click on the firefox.exe icon there?

Comment: as i described, i even tried to open it in cmd, and yes it's there

Comment: @harrymc that what i did exactly as I said in the update.

Comment: You are missing the double-quotes in your edit.

Comment: it does not matter realy, it works this way

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: @Star have you Windows Xp installation disc? If yes then you can attempt a repair but carefully it will downgrade all your updates and service packs if its older service pack than you are using. Also you can try out a system restore as well. Also you can use this [registry hack](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/exefile.htm).

Comment: Also try `Control panel>default program` to set them default. See this http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/restore-exe-file-asso-windows-7-vista-incorrectly-associated/ for win-7

Comment: @avirk sadly it's there is no restore point, and about the repair, I'm not sure if that will work, because it will keep current preferences.
so i guess it will not help, but i will give it a try.

Comment: Check out theis [registry fix](http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/105/1/File-association-fixes-for-Windows-Vista.html) for Vista may be that could help on XP as well but I'm not sure.

Comment: @avirk I will check that out.

Comment: I've updated the Question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Armed with addtional information you've given me via chat:*
Unfortunately it does seem that your PC *may* get somehow infected with malware. 
As an example, [This thread does look very similar to your problems](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/report-a-problem-and-get-troubleshooting-help/S4iItSRPsFc)

Malware or not, root cause of your problems probably lay in this little known registry gem - originally thought to allow easy debbuging: 
[(source)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
To setup an application to launch the debugger automatically

Start the Registry Editor (regedit).
In the Registry Editor, open the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE folder.
Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\currentversion\image file execution options.
Under the Image File Execution Options folder, locate the name of the application you want to debug (myapp.exe, for example). If you cannot find the application you want to debug:
    Right-click the Image File Execution Options folder and choose New Key from the shortcut menu.
    Right-click the new key and choose Rename from the shortcut menu.
    Edit the key name to the name of your application, for example, myapp.exe.
Right-click the myapp.exe folder and choose New String Value from the shortcut menu.
Right-click the new string value and choose Rename from the shortcut menu.
Change the name to debugger.
Right-click the new string value and choose Modify from the shortcut menu.

The Edit String dialog box appears.
In the Value data box, type devenv /debugexe.
Click OK.
From the Registry menu, choose Exit.
```

**Problem being you could (and malware does) put any executable as debugger, effectively running program of your choice instead of original target**.
I was able to replicate your PC behavior adding `Firefox.exe` key with a debugger target of `Iexplore.exe`
To check if that's what affect you, open registry editor, navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\currentversion\image file execution options` and look for `Firefox.exe` and similar entries for programs exhibiting this behavior. Rename any suspicious keys to something else (eg. `Firefox.exe bad`) and re-run the app.

Last but not least - analyze those keys - maybe it will give you a hint of what was the source - and run a thorough scan of your system with a different tool than the one you have installed (if possible - with windows offline)

Edit: 
`Sysinternals Autoruns` (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) comes in handy in checking image hijacks (among many other nice features). Download the tool, run it and unselect `Hide Windows Entries` in `Filter options`, then select `Image Hijacks`:

[image: Autoruns screen]

You may then either simply delete the entry or analyze it further using several options.
There is also a command line version, `autorunsc`. `autorunsc -h` prints image hijacks. Use `autorunsc -?` to see all options.

Comment: That was awsome, I don't how did you figure it out, but really thank you. everything was just as you described. if i could give you another 500 bounty I would. A final Question: I found so many keys there how to know if thy are valid key or not?

Comment: @Star Basically you would need to look for `debugger` value in those keys -but it's difficult to do manually. `Autoruns` from Sysinternals can do it (among other things), I will add it to answer.

Comment: @WMZ: A great answer buddy!!! Hats off!!! :)
Star: You see... indeed it was a registry gem (or bug... :) which was ailing you.
And kudos to me, the chatroom I started was worth it... :P

Comment: @WMZ: Hey, I was trying to replicate it. I'm getting error:
"Windows cannot find the file...." I made a key with "Firefox.exe" & added a string value "debugger" with data "Iexplore.exe" in it.
What am I missing? Need I restart the system.

Comment: @Daredev iexplore.exe is not in the path you need to put full path most likey `c:\program files\internet explorer` and also add protocol (or just `//`) so full value would be similar to `(path)\iexplore.exe http://`. You can also just put notepad.exe or write.exe as I did in the screenshot if you want to try it

Comment: @Daredev And it's not needed to restart. Changes are instant.

Comment: @Daredev Correction - you do not need anything after `iexplore.exe` on XP with IE8 (I just checked). Obviously it behaves differently depending on IE ver/setup (with IE9/w7 it tried download the hijacked executable that's why I fooled it with `//` just to make it unparseable

Comment: @wmz: Well, the full path solution worked perfectly...
A killer of a registry tweak.

Answer (score 3):

New answer:
Try this: http://www.dougknox.com/xp/fileassoc/xp_exe_fix.zip

or otherwise:

1. Open Registry Editor, then navigate to the following key:
   **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\open\command**
2. Double-click the (Default) value in the right pane.
3. Delete the current value data, and then type: **"%1" %***
   (ie., quote-percent-one-quote-space-percent-asterisk.)
4. Navigate to: **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.exe**
5. In the right-pane, set **Data of (default) to exefile**

Exit the Registry Editor.

Hopefully, this solution helps.

Source: http://windowsxp.mvps.org/exefile.htm

PS: It dangerous to simulate this problem, so please keep trying & don't give up... :)

Comment: since i didn't find the keys your talking about, i searched for them in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHIN" and deleted them. and now no exe is opening. :D :D :D :D

Comment: OK, Now I fixed what I damaged. but now I'm certain that is the problem is not related to user setting neither file association.

Comment: I've updated the Question

Comment: @Star: Hey, there has to be a solution, so don't just reinstall windows.
& thanks for taking it sportingly because even I didn't find the above keys, but then I thought that it might be the case that they'll exist in your system.
Nevertheless, I'm searching another method, just don't stop here... :)

Comment: @Star: Please check the value of the following key:
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.exe\OpenWithProgids"
Check NAME, TYPE, DATA. Ideally, they should be exefile, REG_NONE, (zero-length binary value)

Comment: @Star: Did something happened??? Please update the status... :)

Comment: @Daredev: No I didn't find this key, because i removed before

Comment: I tried your new answer, and guess what ........... no diffrent :D.
I've found the value as you said, only the default value was somehow dublicated so I removed both of them and created new one with value you gave me, but still ......

Comment: take a look at the update.

Comment: @Star: No offence. But I feel that you haven't had a relook at the answer. I have completely changed it. Please have a relook.
Have you tried the zip file method as well as the alternate method given there...???

Comment: @Star: Can u come on chat?
Here's the chat room: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/6089/exe-problem?tab=general

Comment: @Daredev: sure no problem, but I assure you i did try file in the you provided, I tried fixing from registry as you told, but nothing is working. I know it's frustrating It's amost a month since i started taking care of this but nothing is working .

Comment: I'm on chat now.

Comment: @Star: Sorry buddy, I had to go then. Ping me whenever you can now... :)

Comment: @Daredev: No problem, and about the time line I will post it in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resetting your IE settings?

1. Create another user (admin)
2. Switch to the newly-created user
3. Run regedit
4. Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
5. Right-click -> export to a public folder or root dir
6. Switch back to your original account
7. Remove the the above key
8. Run the exported .reg for the Internet Settings key.

Comment: I tried creating another user, but it's the same in the other user too. the same apps are opened in IE.