# Internet Explorer opens when I double-click firefox.exe or chrome.exe

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer, opera

I've been experiencing a problem for quite some time from now. I use Windows 7 and I cannot open Google Chrome or Firefox.

When I click on the .EXE it opens Internet Explorer instead of Google Chrome or Firefox. I installed Opera and it works fine. I tried to uninstall Google Chrome and Firefox, ran Kaspersky Antivirus, CCleaner, Autorun, and Avast AntiVirus but the problem persists.

Whatever I do, Internet Explorer keeps opening instead of Google Chrome or Firefox. What might it be? Can anyone give me some ideas?

Here is what I am clicking:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you clicking on a shortcut from your desktop or are you trying to open a file?

Comment: I tryed both, the result is the same, IE opens instead of firefox or chrome.

Comment: Would you mind posting a screenshot of what you're clicking on to try and open the different browsers?

Comment: http://s22.postimg.org/dpwmccyq9/img1.png

Comment: I have also runned malwarebytes but it didnt detect any problems

Comment: http://s4.postimg.org/ctl1t5b4d/Sem_t_tulo.png

Comment: This is most likely a virus, I've encountered one like this which affected chrome only. Maybe try installing avast or AVG antivirus and run a full scan ? Both of them can be downloaded and used for free and are pretty good IMO.

Comment: Can you check the properties of both the exe. Is there any changes happen on in? If possible try to run any boot scan. The spyware can be removed easily by running boot scan.

Comment: check image hijacks (shameless plug) http://superuser.com/questions/479290/applications-are-being-opened-by-ie-instead-of-running-normally/486441#486441

Comment: AUtoruns showed me this image! http://s28.postimg.org/inco7zyzh/autoreuns.png I deleted the registry but when I click on chrome it stills opens IE

Comment: I tryed to delete ie.exe but trustedinstaller doesnt not allow me

Comment: Don't try and delete IE. Follow @wmz's instructions that he linked to and see if that resolves the problem. If that doesn't work, can you please open up the properties window of Firefox and post a screenshot of the digital signature details? (Right click the Firefox executable and click `Properties`, switch to the `Digital Signatures` tab, click the entry below the `Name of signer` column and then click `Details`. Post a screenshot of the window that opens up)

Comment: I disconnected from the internet and ran ADW Cleaner. Right now I'm writing this from a Firefox browser, so it seems problem is solved. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Please answer your question below by using the button.

Comment: @JoaoVitorGomes Others also want to know, what exactly you did to solve the problem. Please write an answer to your own question. That's fine